# Неправильный вывод HTML разметки

Tags: php, html5

Имеет у меня вот такая разметка.

```
<p class="element-p"></p>
```

В неё я размещаю текст, который преобразуется с HTML-сущностей в HTML-символы.

Делаю это так:

```
$TEXT_VALUE = html_entity_decode($result_city['ANONS_TEXT_VALUE']);
```

Преобразуются символы успешно!

Далее результат собираюсь вывести в мою разметку (см. выше).

```
echo '<p class="element-news-p">'. $TEXT_VALUE .'</p>';
```

На выходе я получаю результат не совсем то чего я ожидал.

```
<p class="element-news-p"></p>
<p>описание</p>
<p></p>
```

Хотя ожидалось иной результат:

```
<p class="element-news-p">
    <p>описание</p>
    <p></p>
</p>
```

> Подскажите как решается такое явление ? и почему такое поведение ?

Comment: `<p>` запрещено вкладывать внутрь другого `<p>`.

Comment: надо заметить, что на выходе вы получаете именно то что ожидаете. Просто вы смотрите инспектор дерева, в котором структура показана с учетом коррекции браузера, а смотреть надо исходный код страницы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше заменить `<p class="element-news-p"> '. $TEXT_VALUE .'</p>'` на `<div class="element-news-p">' . $TEXT_VALUE .'</div>'` и подогнать в него соответствующие стили.

Всё потому, что как только браузер видит следующий параграф, он автоматически закроет предыдущий.